# NSArray behaving Weird Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am from C# background and now learning objective C.
I created two NSArrays  1.optionsLabelArray and 2.optionsLabelSubtitleArray initially with two  elements each (optionsLabelArray=>Yes & No) and optionsLabelSubtitleArray(acceptable and action). Now requirement changed and I have to add one more item and I am doing it like below. But It still shows only two elements. 
I tried using NSMutableArray , no luck. Looks like it's a small issue but couldn't figure it out.. any ideas will be appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    optionsLabelArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No",@"No" ,nil]; // here is problem
    optionsLabelSubtitleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Acceptable",@"Action required",@"No", nil]; // here to

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CheckerCell";
    CustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.optionLabel.text = [optionsLabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.optionLabelSubtitle.text = [optionsLabelSubtitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How many rows are you telling the table view there are?

Comment: BTW, your design kinda sucks.  The two arrays (which are your data source) should be "owned" by the data source object (which is "this" above) and should be initiated when the table is created.  Then numberOfRowsInSection should query the array counts to find out how many rows to display.

Comment: I am expecting three rows in the table.. I tried initializing the array in viewDidLoad() also. Its working fine for two rows in the table . I have no much insights .. so missed to assign the parent data object to array(data source).

Comment: You were expecting 3 rows in the table but the table view was only expecting two, since you told it there were two.  It can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need implement following method and return 3 when you increase cell count

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

see more on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: @lance..you are superb.. i have implemented numberOfRowsInSection to return 3 and it solved.  just pasting my code here so that it can help some naive guys like me ;) 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //    return optionsLabelArray.count;
    return 3;
}  cheers,

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the implementation of your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method to support more rows. To do so you probably want to have an implementation where the array is either an instance variable of the class or otherwise consistent between the two methods.

Comment: my array are static..  
static NSArray *optionsLabelArray ;
static NSArray *optionsLabelSubtitleArray ; in the global section of the class.

Comment: If they are static they probably should be initialized elsewhere, perhaps in the initializer. With the current implementation the values get set every time `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called. However, it would be a better design to use instance variables rather than static variables.